# How do you deal with converting sql results to json in a flask app when join statements sometimes do not have data?

Tags: python, json, pandas, postgresql

I've come across what feels like should have a very simple solution, but I cannot think of a good way of solving without doing this the long way...

I'm using flask, and a postgres database. I'm also pulling my data with raw postgres queries, I'm not using any ORMs or anything like that.

Let's imagine I have a flask API I want to serve some data from.

My data is split into 2 tables.

Table 1: user meta data

| username | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| bob | 1 |
| joe | 2 |

Table 2: tracks values over time for each user

| user_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-01-01' | 0 |
| 1 | '2021-01-02' | 1 |
| 1 | '2021-01-03' | 2 |
| 2 | '2021-01-01' | 0 |
| 2 | '2021-01-02' | 1 |
| 2 | '2021-01-03' | 2 |

Let's say that my API has a route that returns a basic json structure for each user that should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "username": bob,
    "values": [
      { "date": "2021-01-01", "value": 0 },
      { "date": "2021-01-02", "value": 1 },
      { "date": "2021-01-03", "value": 2 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "username": joe,
    "values": [
      { "date": "2021-01-01", "value": 0 },
      { "date": "2021-01-02", "value": 1 },
      { "date": "2021-01-03", "value": 2 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I need to figure out how to get this data. The obvious answer to me at first was to just do this:

```
select *
from meta m
left join values v on m.user_id = v.user_id
```

Then I would retrieve the results from the cursor, and then it wouldn't be too difficult to separate it from there between the metadata and the data over time like this.

(Assume that the variable `df` has the postgres representation of my query as a pandas dataframe)

```
# Extract only the meta information as a dataframe
meta = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id'])[['user_id', 'username']].reset_index(drop=True)

# Extract the values as an array which I can merge onto the meta dataframe
values = df[['user_id', 'date', 'value']].groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x['date', 'value'].to_dict('records'))

# Response I can return
response = pd.merge(meta, values.rename('values'), on='user_id', how='left')
```

Now, this code does work. But if you're a smart cookie, you'll notice a major flaw in this approach. And the flaw is...

**What if there are no values over time for a given user?**

This approach relies on the assumption that there would be values to merge onto the meta dataframe.

The only way I know of to solve for this is to make separate psql queries and manually account for emptyness along the way. (My real data structure has multiple nested "values over time" tables so I would have to manually check everything in between queries, so I need a relatively elegant / easy to implement solution).

This MUST be a problem other people have encountered and solved somehow... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out that you can actually return json inside of my sql query. Here's how you can do this...

```
select
  m.username,
  m.user_id,
  coalesce(json_agg(json_build_object('date', date, 'value', value)), '[]') as values
from meta m
left join values v on m.user_id = v.user_id
```

The benefit of this too is that you don't have to do any transformations in python either.